# NodeJS: Deep copy a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to deep copy a function object in NodeJS?  I am trying to use a function that I have set fields on, but I need a way to copy that function so that when I do duplicate it, I can modify these extra fields separately.

For example:

```
let a = function(){console.log('hello world')}
a.__var = 1
let b = clone(a)
a.__var // 1
b.__val // 1
b.__var = 2
a.__var // 1
```

I've tried things like using underscore/lodash, but they seem to convert the function to an object in the clone.  `b` would wind up being `{ __var: 1 }` in the previous example.  I need to be able to perform a deep copy on the function..

Comment: I was thinking maybe `let b = function(){a.call(this, ...arguments)}` might work but that seems sloppy

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: What is the point of copying a function?  We need to know what you're trying to accomplish so we can advise appropriately.

Comment: I am copying the function because I have a package that returns middleware functions, that have to also be tagged with certain fields so that I can identify and manipulate them from the package.  In implementing the ability to allow the user to pass in an existing middleware previously generated by my package and have it combine them, returning a new compounded function with its own unique attributes.  Without a deep copy, those unique attributes mutate the parent middlewares.

Comment: @terpak you should defined *deep*, in "deep clone." I'm going by your code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37639611/124486).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to this that I've used is to `.bind()` the function (which produces a copy of the function) but not bind any actual arguments. If the function has static methods/properties on it, you can use `Object.assign` to copy those on. My use case for doing this was shimming the global `Notification` constructor. Example:

```
// copy the constructor
var NotifConstructor = Notification.bind(Notification);
//assign on static methods and props
var ShimmedNotif = Object.assign(function (title, _opts) { /* impl here that returns NotifConstructor */ }, Notification);
//now you can call it just like you would Notification (and Notification isn't clobbered)
new ShimmedNotif('test');
```

For simpler use cases, `bind` will probably work, e.g.:

```
function hi(name) { console.log('hey ' + name); }
var newHi = hi.bind();
newHi('you'); //=> 'hey you'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired functionality by doing the following:

```
let a = function (){console.log('hello world')}
a.field = 'value'

// Wrap the "cloned" function in a outer function so that fields on the
// outer function don't mutate those of the inner function
let b = function() { return a.call(this, ...arguments) }

b.field = 'different value'
console.log(a.field === b.field) // false
```

Comment: But, if the original function itself is using these properties like `.field`, then the original function will only be using the `a` properties no matter which was the original caller `a` or `b`.  When calling a function, `this` is not set to the function itself unless some caller manually made that be so with `.call()` or `.apply()` which is not normally the case.

Answer (score -2):

## Use [lodash's _.assign(dest, src)](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)

```
let a = function(){console.log('hello world')}
a.__var = 1
```

Then..

```
let b = () => 42;
_.assign(b,a);
b.__var // returns 1
b() // returns 42
```